# pandas get_loc is failing with InvalidIndexError using DatetimeIndex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, indexing

I have a list of source timestamps from a pandas dataframe index.  I'm trying look up the nearest timestamp in another target pandas dataframe. For one dataframe the get_loc() is working, and on the other dataframe it returns an "InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects".  For the life of me, I can't figure out a substantive difference between the two target lists of timestamp indexes.

```
source = df.set_index(['timestamp'].sort_index().index
source[10000:10005]
DatetimeIndex(['2023-04-21 19:35:59.396250', '2023-04-21 19:35:59.475000',
               '2023-04-21 19:35:59.555000', '2023-04-21 19:35:59.635000',
               '2023-04-21 19:35:59.716250'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='timestamp', freq=None)

#both target dataframe indexes are sorted with duplicates removed
target1 = df1.set_index(['timestamp']).sort_index().drop_duplicates()
target2 = df2.set_index(['timestamp']).sort_index().drop_duplicates()

target1.index[5:]
DatetimeIndex(['2023-04-21 19:27:30.869530', '2023-04-21 19:27:31.116220',
               '2023-04-21 19:27:31.364920', '2023-04-21 19:27:31.616380',
               '2023-04-21 19:27:31.880470'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='timestamp', freq=None)
target1.index.max()
Timestamp('2023-04-21 19:58:50.872560')

target2.index[5:]
DatetimeIndex(['2023-04-21 18:58:56.587016', '2023-04-21 18:58:57.587014',
               '2023-04-21 18:58:58.587013', '2023-04-21 18:58:59.587014',
               '2023-04-21 18:59:00.587012'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='timestamp', freq=None)
target2.index.max()
Timestamp('2023-04-21 19:56:48.581202')
```

Looping through the source list timestamps in each target list, I get a different result.  Target2 works and target1 fails.

```
for ts in source[10000:10005]:
    get = target2.index.get_loc(ts,"nearest")
    print("Source:",ts, "Nearest:",target2[get])

Source: 2023-04-21 19:35:59.396250 Nearest: 2023-04-21 19:35:59.581398
Source: 2023-04-21 19:35:59.475000 Nearest: 2023-04-21 19:35:59.581398
Source: 2023-04-21 19:35:59.555000 Nearest: 2023-04-21 19:35:59.581398
Source: 2023-04-21 19:35:59.635000 Nearest: 2023-04-21 19:35:59.581398
Source: 2023-04-21 19:35:59.716250 Nearest: 2023-04-21 19:35:59.581398

for ts in source[10000:10005]:
    get = target1.index.get_loc(ts,"nearest")
    print("Source:",ts, "Nearest:",target1[get])

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidIndexError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_19096/211410640.py in <module>
      1 for ts in source[10000:10005]:
----> 2     get = target1.get_loc(t,"nearest")
      3     print("Source:",ts, "Nearest:",target1[get])

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\datetimes.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
    701 
    702         try:
--> 703             return Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
    704         except KeyError as err:
    705             raise KeyError(orig_key) from err

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3369             tolerance = self._convert_tolerance(tolerance, np.asarray(key))
   3370 
-> 3371         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
   3372         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:
   3373             raise TypeError("get_loc requires scalar valued input")

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_indexer(self, target, method, limit, tolerance)
   3440 
   3441         if not self._index_as_unique:
-> 3442             raise InvalidIndexError(self._requires_unique_msg)
   3443 
   3444         if not self._should_compare(target) and not is_interval_dtype(self.dtype):

InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

What am I missing?

Updated:
table1 is a dataframe of ping results and indeed has duplicated indexes.

```
table1[table1.index.duplicated()].head()
     Name   Client  Target  seq bytes   delay
timestamp                       
2023-04-21 19:28:52.967250  fping   test11041   1.1.1.1 328 64  144.0
2023-04-21 19:34:37.321620  fping   test11041   1.1.1.1 1703    64  749.0
2023-04-21 19:34:37.321620  fping   test11041   1.1.1.1 1705    64  249.0
2023-04-21 19:35:48.729640  fping   test11041   1.1.1.1 1991    64  157.0
2023-04-21 19:36:52.478800  fping   test11041   1.1.1.1 2246    64  156.0
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal version of your DataFrame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your index has duplicates. Drop the duplicate indexes.

```py
target1 = target1[~target1.index.duplicated(keep='first')]
```

Comment: I thought I'd that handled with the initial drop_duplicates on the df, but indeed.. I have duplicated indexes with unique column values.  Thank you.